# IR Barrier with a 555

Tags: 555, infrared

I'm trying to build an IR Barrier with an 555, a sfh4547 and a tssp58038. Here are the datasheets:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf
https://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic0/00209793_0.pdf/SFH%204547.pdf
http://www.vishay.com/docs/82479/tssp58038.pdf

This is the schematic of the emitter:

[image]
An this is the schematic of the receiver:

[image]

I have tested that the emitter has a frequency near 38khz
but always have a 5v output in pin 1 of the tssp58038. I don't know how to make it work.

Update:
Osciloscope at 1v and 5us.

This is the NE555 output:
[image]

This is the base of the Q1:
[image]

This is between Q1 and D1:
[image]

This is between D1 and R5:
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of R8?

Comment: First I'm a newcomer in electronics. This R8 was to try to limit the Amps in TSSP58038. I have the same result without R8.

Comment: Huh?  What's a IR *barrier*?  Seems like you only need a sheet of aluminum foil or sufficiently thick paper for that.

Comment: Sorry, could be a problem with my English, this is what I'm refering to https://www.google.es/search?q=infrared+barrier

Comment: @TlmaK0 I get that. Why do you think you need to limit the current there?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, I thought that the TSSP58038 should work between 0.55mA and 0.9mA, so I have added this resistor to limit the supplied current

Comment: @TlmaK0 No, you need to supply voltage, not current. But if you have the same result without R8, then something else is going on. I'd start by measuring the modulation frequency to see how far you are from 38kHz.

Comment: Next I'd check the voltage at R5, you should see swings between 0V and >3V.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the R8 and I can see 25,5us between every pulse with the osciloscope (39.21khz?) between R5 and SFH, and the voltage oscillates between 1.1V and 4V. Could it be this 1.1V the problem? How to move it to 0V?

Comment: Install 1,000uF on the Transmitter VDD. And examine (OUT) of the 555 when HIGH. Does OUT reach up to VDD?

Comment: Thanks, I have put a 470uF (I don't have a 1000uF now), but the V in r5 still over 1v, the out of 555 is 3V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мost infrared sensors, do not respond very well to a continuous incidence of infrared light. Switching the IR source off, even for a small period, allows IR detectors to ‘recuperate’, and so optimise their ability to minimize the response to ambient light.
Try to use a modulated signal. [Example.](http://www.electroschematics.com/782/infrared-light-barrier/)

Comment: Thnaks AltAir, are you sure that I need to implement this kind of circuit only for make it work for a seconds? My receiver should show something at least at intervals, don't you think?

Comment: The scheme I showed as an example works continuously.
 The problem with the scheme you are using is the use of the infrared module (tssp58038) in a non-typical mode of operation. Where do you try to use this infrared barrier? Why did you choose this scheme? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I did it from scratch, probably I didn't understand correctly the tssp58038 datasheet, where it says that I should modulate the signal?

Comment: Connect the oscilloscope to the infrared receiver output. Then, at the moment of turning on the transmitter, the signal on the receiver should go down to the low level. This will mean that the transmitter works but requires a modulate the signal. To check the receiver, you can use any infrared remote control. In this case, the oscilloscope must show pulse packs.

Comment: TlmaK0, Features: Uses modulated bursts at 38 kHz, Description: Uses modulated bursts at 38 kHz.

Comment: Thanks @AltAir, do you know another IR receiver that doesn't need this modulation?. The barrier will be used inside a little box.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the symptoms you have described in comments, your Q1 BJT never closes completely, resulting in a substantial amount of current (about 20mA) constantly flowing through the LEDs. The receiver then gets a continuous signal instead of a pulsed one, and ignores it. This is by design, so that the receiver could work in the presence of external constant IR, like sunlight.

Check out the output of NE555: it should go below 0.5V for the transistor to be closed. If it doesn't, you may want to replace your NE555 chip. If it does, try replacing the transistor.

Comment: Thanks @Dmiltry, the collector of the Q1 oscillates between 0 and 3.5V, but between R5 and D1, it's between 1.1 and 4V

Comment: @TlmaK0 I'm not sure what your comment is getting at, since I was talking about the output of NE555, which is connected to the base, not the collector. Incidentally, the voltage at the collector of a closed transistor should be more than 3.5V, and the voltage across the closed BJT+LED (that is, between R5 and D1) should be practically equal to VCC. If you see 4V there, the BJT is not getting closed properly.

Comment: @Dmiltry I have updated the question with oscilloscope captures